# What do you put for company location on a resume/job application in this scenario?

Tags: job-search, resume, hiring-process, job-change

So I work for a company that's located in city A.

My position was originally physically located at this company in city A.

It was then changed to remote after COVID hit.

However, my company purchased a smaller company in another location called city B. The smaller company still operates under its own name  (which makes me more confused).

My job role now operates at this location in city B when required to physically be there, otherwise I am remote.

So what do I put for company location on job applications and on my resume?

City A is where the company HQ is at.

City B is a small little office.

I am super confused.

Comment: This question would probably benefit from a location tag as we're seeing regional differences in what the location on a resume/CV is supposed to indicate in the answers and comments.

Answer (score 72):

I've never put the location of companies on my CV, and I don't often see it on other people's. Why not just leave it off and avoid the whole problem?

Comment: I've been advised by career counselors to put the town on resumes.

Comment: @Gh0stFish If you're not seeing any on CV's, you may have moved into a segment of the job market where location ceased to matter as much. If you're working at a Starbucks, handling LA glamour requires a wildly different skillset than a rough neighborhood. In retail, location implies audience and carries prestige. It might also be customary - to the point where your CV is not considered without. Last reason: To disambiguate unrelated companies that share a name (Entirely unrelated, or franchisees of a chain.).

Comment: @Davidw I would only do that if it is a small business with an ambiguous name, so you wouldn't find it just by the name. For example, if you worked at "Luigi's Pizza", then you might want to mention it's the Luigi's Pizza in Somewheretown with the Michelin star, not the one in Otherplaceington which went out of business after the health inspectors declared it a superfund site. But when it's a large company people in the industry should know about, then the location is rather irrelevant.

Comment: This may vary by culture, but in the US, location is a required field on many application websites, including most Workday sites in my experience.

Comment: @Davidw Many career counselors are now recommending the opposite. Adding a location can sometimes result in your application being summarily deleted because a company would rather not pay relocation expenses. Wait until they think you're the perfect candidate before you talk about stuff like that.

Comment: @Strikegently And such systems will often auto fill values from resumes.

Answer (score 56):

Since you worked at both locations, just list them both:

```
since 2015: Frobnicator at Foo Corp.
            Locations: City A, City B, work from home.
```

Comment: This is what I normally see.  As for the company name, use whatever name is on your paycheck as that's usually what will come up when they check references.

Answer (score 12):

> So what do I put for company location on Job Applications and on my Resume?

Look at your contract. It has the company's full address on it. Unless specifically asked not for the company address, but your location of work, that address in your contract is the "company address".

The reason for this is that depending on juristiction lines and who makes sure company names are unique, "Uncle Bob's Cafe" in A and "Uncle Bob's Cafe" in B might be different companies. Branches of a huge corporation might be totally different between locations. And if someone would look up "Uncle Bob's Cafe" in B, they would not even find that as a registered company. So make sure you put the location that is their official location, not your place of work. If you need to emphasize that you were not on site, do so on it's own line or information field.

Comment: Great explanation! You provide the employer a location to distinguish different legal entities of the same name, but also to communicate cultural fit.

Answer (score 4):

If someone were going to mail something work related to you, where you would you tell them to mail it? Use that address.

Comment: This is intelligent. *The* address is where you're reachable.

Comment: This applies to email signatures, but I don't see how it applies to a CV. I suppose it's a heuristic that will often result in a correct and useful location. OP's situation may be an exception: 'Employed by entity X-at-A, but posted at office B'. You'd use location A in order to indicate the legal entity, but you might mention that you were posted at B if that is culturally or contextually significant.

Comment: @MvZ This appears to be a cultural/regional issue. Where I live the expectation is that the location on your resume is where *you* worked, not where the main office happens to be located.

Comment: If you're asking for something to be mailed you would choose the office where you could collect it, not necessarily where you or your supervisor were formally located or where anyone wishing to inquire about the company would contact the company.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't really matter, put either.

You'd be perfectly justified in picking either one since you worked at both. So if I were you, I'd pick whichever one you think will impress the hiring manager more.

Answer (score 3):

As @Gh0stFish wrote putting a location is not necessary. However usually when you apply for a new job most of the times you know where the job is located, unless you are applying for a big company that has multiple vacancies in different locations. Since now you are actually working for a company based in two different cities the recruiter might not know your preferred location. So, if you really want to put a location on the CV put the one that will be the most convenient for your commute. You already know that remote work often requires physical presence, but you should also take into account that often the conditions change and the remote work is turned into a regular office work.

Try and minimise the risk of getting stuck into a long commute.

Answer (score 0):

I would put hybrid on location/remote and put both locations. I am based in the U.S.  I once worked remotely for a company in NY (far from my location) and it really made for a lengthy background-check process, but people should recognize hybrid work in this era.

If you apply to remote work, it's re-assuring to them that you have teleworked before.

Many companies and organizations still want people to be on-sight, at least part of the time, however.